# Old Backbone View Causing extra Event Triggers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

OK, I've done some reading on this and I'm pretty sure I know what the problem relates to I Just don't know the best way to fix it. I've got the standard backbone router that sets me up with an item details view, then when I click on a button called "start" it creates a new view which takes me to a sort of a game that people can play with some buttons on the bottom that have "click" events attached. This second view is not called through the router but directly from the first view.

The problem is the second time someones goes back to the homescreen and does it again, this time there are two events attached to each button. The third time there are three events. Obviously the original views are still listening to these buttons. I've read about this and calling the Remove() method but is this what I need to do? If so where do I call remove? Relevant Code below:

1ST VIEW

```
window.GameDrillView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        "click .start" : "startGameDrill",
    },


 startGameDrill: function () {
  var start = $('#start').val();.
  var stop = $('#stop').val();.
   var StartView = new GameDrillStartView({model: this.model, el: $('#content')[0], start: start, stop:stop});

}
```

});

START VIEW

```
window.GameDrillStartView = Backbone.View.extend({

   // declare variables
    initialize: function () {
    this.render();
    },

        events: {
            "click .nextstage"   : "nextstage",  // 2ND TIME THROUGH GETS CALLED TWICE

        },

 nextstage: function () {

      // Do some stuff // 

      this.render(); //Re-render
},

    render: function () {

       // Do some variables stuff

      this.$el.html(this.template(jQuery.extend(this.model.toJSON(), extended_options)));..
        return this;
    }   
});
```

Comment: You have the right idea, so the question is, when is the view that you create no longer in use? Is it a UI element that the user "closes"? If so, that's where you want it to remove itself.

Answer (score 1):

When changing view you need to call `undelegateEvents()` method from the `Backbone.View`. It disable listening all the elements events mentioned in `events { }` block. Also if you need to destroy old view you can call `remove()` method of the view which will call `undelegateEvents()` internally.

update (example from official site)

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "help":                 "help",    // #help
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
  },

  help: function() {
    if (this.currentView)
       this.currentView.undelegateEvents();

    this.currentView = new HelpView();
  },

  search: function(query, page) {
    if (this.currentView)
       this.currentView.undelegateEvents();

    this.currentView = new SearchView();
  }

});
```

Comment: OK, but where do I call undelegateEvents() or remove()? The problem happens when someone mid-view clicks back to the home page and then returns. So I guess I need to call undelegateEvents() as the first thing on every  view that has a hyperlink attached to it?

Comment: You need call `undelegateEvents` every time when you changing the view. Otherwise you need to keep your views instances and initialize them only once. I assume that you have code for views instantiating in your route. Assign your view to the inner variable of your route (ex. `currentView`) and then when you need to create new view - release the `currentView`.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but I'm getting an error that this.ListView.undelegateEvents is not a function I'll see if I can figure out why

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create only one instance of the view:

```
if(_.isUndefined(this.StartView))
    this.StartView = new GameDrillStartView({model: this.model, el: $('#content')[0], start: start, stop:stop});
else
    this.StartView.render();
```

In the render method of GameDrillStartView add the empty method

```
this.$el.html(this.template(jQuery.extend(this.model.toJSON(), extended_options)))
```

In this way you won't add more event listeners but you'll update the page everytime the user presses the button.

You can manage the life cycle of `StartView` in GameDrillView since it seems like a better place to do so.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to do *one* of those? Or both? And do you know why this problem doesn't happen when you go through the Backbone router? For example View #1 is called from the backbone router and it also has click events and nothing to check that it's previously been created however it does not have this same problem.

Comment: I removed the change I did in your render method. it's not necessary since you're using the html() method to render your template. Just follow the first one. 

About your question, it has to do with event delegation. Backbone attach events to the $el property of the view that represents the DOM element related with that view. Maybe the element ($el) attached to the view created by the Router is created everytime the route is triggered. That clean all the listeners attached to that view. In the case of the second view, $el always exists and you attach event listeners multiple times to it

Answer (score 0):

Got same trouble. Messy solution:

```
var current_view = false;
var prev_view = false;
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "events/:id": "viewEvent",
    }
});

var app_router = new AppRouter;

app_router.on('route:viewEvent', function (event_id) {
    var _event = new Event({id:event_id});
    current_view = new EventView({ 
        model: _event, 
    });
});

//Will be called after route:viewEvent
app_router.on('route', function () { 
    if(prev_view) {
        prev_view.undelegateEvents();
    }
    prev_view = current_view;
});
```

Not sure, how to make it without having `current_view` and `prev_view` out of router scope.